# FileUtils.move not working in Mirth

Tags: mirth

Greetings for the day !!.

I am trying to move a file from one location to another location if it fails on header validation .

Because the file is containing more than 10,000 records and i have enabled batch processing.

If header of file is wrong, I don't want it to iterate through entire 10,000 records and want to move file on header level validation .

I am trying to use `FileUtils.moveFile(src,dest)`, but its throwing below error.

Can you please help me in this , how can i make it successful here .

I am not able to attach my channel .

```
[2015-07-30 20:36:41,398] ERROR (postprocessor:?): :: Message Errored BecauseJavaException: java.io.IOException: Failed to delete original file 'C:\Users\Admin\Documents\MirthExamples\csvexample s\File Reader\processed_30-07-15_19-22-42.483.csv' after copy to 'C:\Users\Admin\Documents\MirthExamples\csvexample s\error\20150730083641.csv'
```

Comment: Either your file is still in use by another process, or it has read-only attribute. Have you checked that? Try copyFile and then forceDelete of the same class.

Comment: Thanks for reply, File is in use by another process but i want to close it . it is possible and if yes , how can i do that .

Comment: Typically it's done by a try-catch-finally block in the process that's _opened_ the file in the first place. If that process is still holding the file and you are trying to close it in another place, then, probably, is something wrong in your system design.